# Provide default or hard coded values to attributes Dotnetcasclient

Tags: .net, dll

This is my first attempt to work and use DotNetCashClient.dll . I am trying to provide hard coded values using this library. Basically we have a .net code that is using this library. And using this code we are retrieving attributes like username, email id and so on. But I am told to use or replace the reference  with another DotNetCasClient.dll which which will read hard coded values for usernames or have hard coded values in a config file for usernames . Basically they want create that library so that it will be easier for any developer to test the project during the development which will avoid entering credentials again and again while testing the application. I am not sure if we can do that or how we can do that. Kindly looking for help .

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to skip the authentication for some users in lower environment to testing. If this is correct try to explore ["notAuthorizedUrl"](https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client) configuration settings in DotNetCashClient.

If this has to be user specific then I you may need to update the source code and create your customized dll.
Get the source code from https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client.git

Comment: sorry I have miss understand your comment. may be because i am still not aware how CAS works. I want to skip authentication for users while testing. Even I would appreciate if we can make it user specific where exactly I need To change source code. Help will be strongly appreciated .

Comment: I have notAuthorizedUrl="~/NotAuthorized.aspx" in my config file. Should I change it to notAuthorizedUrl=No . Where I can check which values we can pass to these settings.

Comment: Is there any way where we can create an interface that skips the CAS authentication and just distribute source attributes.